# Python: How to fill/append data from python loop to SQL table?

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a python script in Pycharm that works like a charm... But these days I'm sensing that I could have a problem with size of monthly `.csv` file and also I would like to analyze data using SQL over Python so I could automatize process and make charts, pies from that queries.

**So instead of exporting to csv I would like to append to SQL table.**

Here is a part of code that exports data to .csv:

```
for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('companychatroom'):
        people = content.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="theid"]').text
        if people != "Monthy" and people != "Python" :
            pass
            mybook = open(r'C:\Users\Director\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\Employees\archive' + datetime.now().strftime("%m_%y") + '.csv', 'a')
            mybook.write('%20s,%20s\n'%(people, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")))
            mybook.close()
```

**================== EDIT: ==============**

I tried over sqlite3 and these is what I could manage to write by now and it works... **But how to append data into SQL table it always overwrite previous with INSERT TO and it shouldn't?**

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

sqlite_file = (r"C:\Users\Director\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\Employees\MyDatabase.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cursor = conn.cursor()

table_name = 'Archive' + datetime.now().strftime("%m_%y")

sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table_name + '("first_name" varchar NOT NULL, "Currdat"date NOT NULL)'
cursor.execute(sql)

sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + table_name + '(first_name,Currdat) VALUES ("value1",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);'
cursor.execute(sql)


sql = 'SELECT * FROM Archive06_16 '
for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print(row)

cursor.close()
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Does your code work? If it doesn't, what errors are you getting? What is your expected vs actual results?

Comment: If all you want is analytics over a columnar dataset, then Pandas can do that. You don't need to use SQL unless you need to persist the data

Comment: @R Nar instead of exporting to csv I would like to append data to SQL table.  @cricket_007 Yes data must persist

Comment: Have you tried using an INSERT SQL statement?

Comment: Im trying with INSERT INTO but error occures because in column 2 is set date and I don't know what format to write instead of these `Thisdate = datetime.now()`